# How to make PUT request with basic auth in C#

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

I am working on web API for the first time and here I am stuck, I want to make a PUT request in Rest API. But all I get is Server ERROR code 500
Below is my code ,Please mark my mistake or correct my code .

```
  string TargetUrl = BaseAPIUrl + "/devices/" + 8931088717107028617;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Username + ":" + APIKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

       string myJson = "{ \"status\": \"DEACTIVATED\" }";

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(TargetUrl, new StringContent(myJson))
```

In response i get Server Error code :500

Comment: Have you checked the server's error log?

Comment: 500 means the server is doing something wrong, not the client, though the client might ALSO be doing something wrong. You say *PUT* in the title but are using `PostAsync`, is that the issue, perhaps?

Comment: Same Error with PUT request ...
Example request url looks like ths
curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Basic ZHB0cmlhbFZXIxOmQ3MtNDMxOC1hZTBkLTBmNjA5MmIyZTZhYg==" -d "{ \"status\": \"DEACTIVATED\" }" "https://test.com/rws/api/v1/devices/{iccid}"

Comment: @pankashmann that URL in the last comment you made appears to be missing a slash before the iccide placeholder